# partial page postback using javascript/jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two asp.net updatepanels on my page. One of them has a checkbox and other one has some labels. I want to update the contents of second updatepanel when checkbox is checked/unchecked. I am using following code:

```
 var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
 prm._doPostBack('UpdatePanel2', '');
```

but it is doing full page post back.

Please suggest a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can set checkbox's AutoPostback to True and make it a trigger of the second UpdatePanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="CheckBox1" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And then you can add label changing code in checkbox's "CheckedChanged" event handler, e.g.

```
protected void CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label2.Text = DateAndTime.Now;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for update panel triggers, you don't need to trigger it by javascript...